# Isotope - jQuery - Images stack on each other after content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic content website (only one page) and using isotope for the first tab only. I will explain what do I get - my question is - how do I fix this?

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Type hr in the search field.
2. Open the "Room Location" tab.
3. Clear the hr from the search field.
4. Open the "Company Roster" tab.

There goes my pen - https://codepen.io/vmvelev/pen/rPMjRo

```
var qsRegex;
var $grid = $('.row').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.employee',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function () {
        return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match(qsRegex) : true;
    }
});
var $quicksearch = $('#searchField').keyup(debounce(function () {
    qsRegex = new RegExp($quicksearch.val(), 'gi');
    $grid.isotope();
}, 100));

function debounce(fn, threshold) {
    var timeout;
    threshold = threshold || 100;
    return function debounced() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        var args = arguments;
        var _this = this;

        function delayed() {
            fn.apply(_this, args);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold);
    };
}
```

The problem is that the pictures are stacked. When you type something (even space) in the search, it arranges them as they should. Here is a gif:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7597032/51905257-6ddb5480-23c9-11e9-9e17-8e9202276cb6.gif